# To detect a fall

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am developing an app which accesses accelerometer in order to detect a fall by measuring the values of acceleration in x,y and z directions. Below is my code, I have applied algorithm which uses two threshold values(min and max) rest of the algo you can see in the code itself. The problem i am facing is that the app is not displaying toast i have done some mild experiments with my friend's phone. 
After dropping my phone from a certain height(approximately 30 cm.) and catching it. But no toast appear on the screen.I am unable to identify whether there is a problem in my ALGO or TOAST. I don't know what to do next please help.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (started) {
        double x = event.values[0];
        double y = event.values[1];
        double z = event.values[2];
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Data data = new Data(timestamp, x, y, z);
        sensorData.add(data);
    }

    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        double gacc=SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY;
        double a=event.values[0];
        double b=event.values[1];
        double c=event.values[2];
        long mintime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean min = false;
        boolean max = false;
        int m = 0;
        double xyz=Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a,2)+Math.pow(b,2)+Math.pow(c,2)));

        if(xyz<=3.0){
            min = true;
        }
        if(min==true){
            m++;
            if(xyz>=14){
                max=true;
            }
        }
        if(min && max==true){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"FALL DETECTED!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            m=0;
            min=false;
            max=false;
        }
        if (m>4) {
            m=0;
            min=false;
            max=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So record all of the x,y,z accelerometer values into a file. The point is to collect sensor values when you do different things and see if your program would be triggered by anything.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Of what use will that be ? Could you explain a bit ? BTW Is there any mistake in my code ?

Comment: How do you know if your thresholds are the right values? You can log the accelerometer values and see if they are the right values as it is hard to live debug a falling phone. Also you will find out that sensor data is noisy and bounces around a lot. Good luck.